# stash PR after git rebase for huge amount of code

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I tried to go with `git rebase` being on some `feature-branch`, applying `master` branch on it (well rebassing ON master), wich was way ahead that future branch. (master has more new commits than feature branch)

So,

```
git branch  : feature-branch
git rebase master
[resolving conflicts]
git rebase --continue
[resolving conflicts]
git rebase --continue
git push -f origin feature-branch
```

Then I created a PR ([Pull Request](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+pull+requests+in+Stash)) to `upstream` and in the changes list (still) see conflicts between `upstream` and `origin`!

Why is that?

Is there some setting, like git-config i should tune?

--

For smaller bunch of code I never had that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your local master branch may not be  up to date with origin/master.

Did try 'git rebase origin/master'?

Comment: the master is up to date. that was my first thought too. I did remove it from origin and re-created again from scratch 'git co -b master upstream/master' then set to 'git branch --set-upstream-to=origin' so then with 'git branch -vv' I saw proper set for it.